# ¿Cómo se borran los documentos creados después de una determinada fecha en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Estoy en la aplicación Atlas y he añadido el domingo 22 de noviembre una serie de documentos que quiero borrar.

¿Cómo puedo  borrar los documentos creados después de una determinada fecha en MongoDB?

Busqué en Internet, pero principalmente encontré cómo borrar antes, y nada sobre cómo hacerlo desde la aplicación MongoDB.

Principalmente uso la pitón de otra manera cuando quiero manipular el lado del cliente

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Puedes mostrar algo de lo que hayas intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Hay una opción en MongoDB que son los indices TTL (time-to-live). Estos indices se generan sobre una colección y tiene varias formas de configurarlo, indicarle el tiempo de expiración para todos los documentos o también indicando en cada documento cuando quiere que se expire.

Si necesitas mas información te dejo el enlace de [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)

Si te surgen alguna consulta, no dudes en preguntar ya que esto lo he usado alguna vez y se como funcionan.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Un saludo